# Why does blender crash when my missile disapears in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

In the following scene, I have a camera parented to a missile. When the missile collides with any collision mesh, it disappears. The logic setup is pictured below.

[image: logic setup of missile.]
However, when the missile disappears, blender crashes.
Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: you should probably report this as a bug at http://developer.blender.org

Comment: @X-27 Ideally blender wouldn't crash, even when given nonsensical things to do, so on that point I agree it could be considered a bug. It's indeed nice to have a workaround/correct solution for other users looking on google, and closing the question won't interfere with that. It will still be here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because the camera is parented to the missile. When the missile disappears, so does the camera. When the camera disappears, there is no longer anything sending the output to the display. This creates the problem, because blender can't update the display, and Blender crashes. You can fix this by having a *scene actuator* to set the camera to a different one. Then there will still be something sending output to the display. Logic setup below.
[image: fix logic problem]