# Blender crashes when playing (P) a duplicate scene in BGE

Tags: game-engine, scene

I was making a game with objects that contain pretty complicated programming in the logic bricks. I want to make a new level with the same objects but just with a new venue. I just copy the items I need to the buffer and paste them in a new scene. When I click 'p' in that scene blender just closes directly. Same thing when making a new scene by linking the objects or object data and even with a full copy. Does anyone know what causes this problmem???

Comment: Probably a bug which should be reported to the [tracker](https://developer.blender.org/).

Comment: make sure all of your logic bricks are still linked correctly, if object names change things can break. Also check your [camera](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18938/2217).

Comment: How much logic bricks is there? I've heard they are cause more lag than python, perhaps too much lag in your case?

Comment: It is not a lag issue - it crashes. Crashes are bugs. SE is not for bug reports.